# Trying to push StackScreen in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Whenever I activate the onPress method by tapping on a message, the MessageScreen component just re-renders rather than displaying ChatScreen. This happens even if I replace ChatScreen with any other screen. Any help on the matter is much appreciated.

App.js

```
<NavigationContainer ref={containerRef} initialState={initialNavigationState}>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{swipeEnabled: false}} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStack} options={{swipeEnabled: false}} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

BottomTabNavigator

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function BottomTabNavigator({ navigation, route }) {

{...HomeStack Code}

{...ProfileStack Code}

const MyMessagesStack = createStackNavigator();
function MessagesStack() {
  return (
    <MyMessagesStack.Navigator initialRouteName={"Messages"} 
    screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <MyMessagesStack.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesScreen} />
      <MyMessagesStack.Screen name="Chats" component={ChatScreen} />
    </MyMessagesStack.Navigator>
    );
}

return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME} >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStack}
        options={{title: 'Feed'}}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Messages"
        component={MessagesStack}
        options={{title: 'Messages'}}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStack}
        options={{title: 'Profile'}}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

MessageScreen.js

```
//flatscreen to render message components
</View>
        <FlatList
        data={Data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Chats')} >
            <Message
              image={item.image}
              name={item.name}
              lastMessage={item.message}
              timeStamp={item.timestamp}
              opened
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
```

Comment: Your component is functional or class based?

Comment: @AliHayder it is functional

Comment: Don't create components inside components. Move all of them to outside.

Comment: @satya164 I only create the stacks inside components as that's how it was done in the RN 5 docs

Comment: Where is it done that way in docs?

Comment: @satya164 https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

Comment: I don't see where it's creating components inside another component. It's for nesting navigators, not for creating components - when you write `function Something` inside another `function Something`

Comment: @satya164 ha! wow, that was the problem. Can you publish this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your components are remounting is because there are components defined inside other components:

```js
function BottomTabNavigator() {

  // Here
  function MessagesStack() {
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

You need to define them outside to avoid that:

```js
function MessagesStack() {
  // ...
}

function BottomTabNavigator() {
  // ...
}
```